# error in making a series of standards out of a stock solution

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I want to make a series of standards to make a calibration curve. The analyte is a volatile substance so I'll have to use some glass "containers" with a membrane lit so I don't lose too much of the analyte. The glass container has a certain volume so when making my stock solution the amount of solvent I will use is fixed.

So if I use a big amount of analyt to make my stock solution I will have to use a small amount of stock solution to make the desired concentrations of standards

And if I want to use a big amount of analyte to make my standards I will have to make a low concentration stock solution. Which means a low amount of analyte, because the amount of solvent I can use is fixed by having to use the container with the membrane lit.

When I make stock solution:  If I add a greater amount of analyte the error on the concentration I want to make will become smaller

When I make a standard from this stock solution it's the same thing: If I add a bigger amount of analyte, the error on the concentration I want to make will become smaller.

My question:
Which of the two will have a bigger effect? Or, in other words, is it more important that the error on making my stock solution is smaller or is it more important that the error on making my standard is smaller? I ask this because I will have to choose.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Now I'm thinking my analyte is ofcourse more volatile then my stock solution so there is a bigger chance of an error there. So better to make  the stock solution more accurate

Comment: Sorry is very difficult to understand the logic  under which the restraints you mention emerge. By the way you should use the most concentrated one and operate by dilution just prior  of the measurements.  And work as fast as possible. It can be even difficult but at least you can check if is feasible or not

Comment: Thanks anyway :) I'll just try it and see how it works out!